# Account Lookup field is not saved in record edit form

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

I have custom button in Opportunity. On click of button i am creating a quote. I want to populate Opportunity name and account id and few fields in quote. Here all my fields are there in quote creatin except account id. Can you please help me

```
<div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12">

              <lightning-input-field field-name="AccountId" value={accountObj.Id} disabled="true">

              </lightning-input-field>

           </div>



handleSubmit(event) {

    this.isLoading = true;

    event.preventDefault();       // stop the form from submitting

    const fields = event.detail.fields;

    console.log('Fields ==>', JSON.stringify(fields));

    fields.AccountId = this.accountObj.Id;

    fields.Name = this.quoteName;
    fields.Description = this.Descrip;

    console.log("Fields =====> 2", JSON.stringify(fields));

    this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] to show how the `this.accountObj` is initialized.

Comment: Agree with @PhilW that more context is needed. The quickest route to your solution might be to open developer tools in your browser, set a breakpoint in your handleSubmit method, and step through - checking the values as you go. You should be able to step into the submit method on the last line as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Account Name is a read-only field, and is automatically set from the Opportunity.

[Quote fields](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.quotes_fields.htm&type=5):

> | Field | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | Account Name | The name of the account that the quote’s opportunity is linked to. (Read only.) |